# Matplotlib legend was not displayed properly

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geospatial, geopandas

I am trying to plot the same geospatial data reading this tutorial:

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/geospatial-data-python

But the legend of her final graph has shwown wind speed in ranges. But when I used the same code mentioned on her tutorial, I could not produce the same legend. Any thing missing in her code? or What is wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is, we neither know which versions of the libraries the tutorial uses, not which version you use. Relevant in this case would be pandas, geopandas and matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The categorical legend entries are provided via [PySAL](https://github.com/pysal/pysal), and seem to need the `scheme=<>` and `legend=True` arguments.  Perhaps these were set by default in previous versions of the libraries.    For me, the following works ok:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20, 20))
base = country[country['NAME'].isin(['Alaska','Hawaii']) == False].plot(
    ax=ax, color='#3B3C6E')
florence.plot(
    ax=ax, column='Wind', marker="<", markersize=10, 
    cmap='cool', scheme="Quantiles", legend=True)
plt.axis('off')
```

[image: reproduction]

Unfortunately the markers do not seem to be inherited into the legend, but the colors are the more salient difference anyway.

The [geopandas.plot docs](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot) indicate 3 supported schemes: Quantiles, Equal_interval, fisher_jenks -- the first one seems to correspond to the datacamp example chart.  See also the parameter `k` which defines the number of classes (5 is default as this example).

Comment: @kyaw could you elaborate what does not work? I used geopandas 0.4.0, pysal 1.14.4, pandas 0.23.4, matplotlib 2.2.2.